# run code every 10 minutes when app is Terminate

Tags: ios, backgroundworker

I want to run a code every ten minutes for ever. I used a NSTimer but when the app is in Background or Terminate the timer stops. I developed a game

Comment: how can loose one point for every 10 minutes ?

Comment: Why does the game need to continue when it's been terminated?

Comment: because it is a pet game and it something like real life game

Comment: I still don't understand why it needs to run the background.  Why not record when the game terminates and when the game re-starts, just simulate what has happened during that time.  You don't actually need to run the simulation in real time.

Comment: Ok this is very simple and good idea. Thanks sometime the brain stucks

Comment: adBODKAt has basically the same idea, so you should upvote and accept his answer.

Comment: Yes of course. I should wait one min

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store time, when app is terminated(or send background). When user open your app in next time, load this time. Check with current time and make changes in points.